# ipython pandas crosstab memory error

Tags: pandas, ipython, crosstab, large-data

I am new to ipython and pandas

When I run **pd.crosstab(df['A'], df['B'])**. It has error **MemoryError**

The dataframe has 10,000,000 rows. I think maybe the size of data is too large.

I check the size of dataframe with **df.values.nbytes + df.index.nbytes + df.columns.nbytes**

The memory is only **381 MB**. My server has **16GB ram**

If I run the dataframe with 1,000,000 rows, there is no problem.

I hope someone can help.

*The debug log for error:*

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
MemoryError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-6-199f99c3064f> in <module>()
     99 df = df.applymap(lambda x: np.nan if str(x) == "N/A" or len(str(x).strip()) == 0 else x)
    100 
--> 101 summary_table(df)

<ipython-input-6-199f99c3064f> in summary_table(df)
     78     dis_for_cont_vars(df)
     79 
---> 80     value_count(df)
     81 #END summary_table
     82 

<ipython-input-6-199f99c3064f> in value_count(df)
     63 def value_count(df):
     64     print "===> Value counts\n"
---> 65     print pd.crosstab(df['A'], df['B'])
     66     print "===>\n"
     67 

/home/deploy/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/tools/pivot.pyc in crosstab(rows, cols, values, rownames, colnames, aggfunc, margins, dropna)
    368         df['__dummy__'] = 0
    369         table = df.pivot_table('__dummy__', rows=rownames, cols=colnames,
--> 370                                aggfunc=len, margins=margins, dropna=dropna)
    371         return table.fillna(0).astype(np.int64)
    372     else:

/home/deploy/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/tools/pivot.pyc in pivot_table(data, values, rows, cols, aggfunc, fill_value, margins, dropna)
    108         to_unstack = [agged.index.names[i]
    109                       for i in range(len(rows), len(keys))]
--> 110         table = agged.unstack(to_unstack)
    111 
    112     if not dropna:

/home/deploy/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.pyc in unstack(self, level)
   3211         """
   3212         from pandas.core.reshape import unstack
-> 3213         return unstack(self, level)
   3214 
   3215     #----------------------------------------------------------------------

/home/deploy/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/reshape.pyc in unstack(obj, level)
    416 def unstack(obj, level):
    417     if isinstance(level, (tuple, list)):
--> 418         return _unstack_multiple(obj, level)
    419 
    420     if isinstance(obj, DataFrame):

/home/deploy/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/reshape.pyc in _unstack_multiple(data, clocs)
    316                           columns=data.columns)
    317 
--> 318         unstacked = dummy.unstack('__placeholder__')
    319         if isinstance(unstacked, Series):
    320             unstcols = unstacked.index

/home/deploy/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.pyc in unstack(self, level)
   3211         """
   3212         from pandas.core.reshape import unstack
-> 3213         return unstack(self, level)
   3214 
   3215     #----------------------------------------------------------------------

/home/deploy/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/reshape.pyc in unstack(obj, level)
    420     if isinstance(obj, DataFrame):
    421         if isinstance(obj.index, MultiIndex):
--> 422             return _unstack_frame(obj, level)
    423         else:
    424             return obj.T.stack(dropna=False)

/home/deploy/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/reshape.pyc in _unstack_frame(obj, level)
    459         unstacker = _Unstacker(obj.values, obj.index, level=level,
    460                                value_columns=obj.columns)
--> 461         return unstacker.get_result()
    462 
    463 

/home/deploy/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/reshape.pyc in get_result(self)
    141         # TODO: find a better way than this masking business
    142 
--> 143         values, value_mask = self.get_new_values()
    144         columns = self.get_new_columns()
    145         index = self.get_new_index()

/home/deploy/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/reshape.pyc in get_new_values(self)
    185         else:
    186             dtype, fill_value = _maybe_promote(values.dtype)
--> 187             new_values = np.empty(result_shape, dtype=dtype)
    188             new_values.fill(fill_value)
    189 

MemoryError:
```

Comment: I find myself that when I use crosstab the memory is used more than 16GB so that the task crash

Answer (score 1):

The question is quite old, but for anyone who has the same problem:
The reason why a memory error is encountered, is because the resulting table is of shape (m x n),
where m is the number of unique values in df.A and n is the number of unique values in df.B ... so it can get quite big.

To circumvent this you can try to use sklearn's DictVectorizer instead, which does something similar to crosstab (e.g. can be use to dummy code categorical features), but it generates a sparse matrix, which is more likely to fit into memory.

Answer (score 1):

Yo can use [scipy.sparse.coo_matrix](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.16.0/reference/generated/scipy.sparse.coo_matrix.html), is a matrix which stores (i,j,v) being i df[A] indices, j df[B] indices, and v its value. (Or 1 in case of crosstab).

The last way to instantiate this matrix could be your way, you have to track your label-index in a dict or another variable, but it is super fast and memory affordable.

You have to be concious you wont have a DataFrame any longer, but a numpy array.